ANTLR - Odata Grammar doesnt work with double quote
i am actually writing a parser for OData and I am trying to get it running with the test input '{"Number":"Four"}'. But he can't parse it. When I replace line : '"' ALLOWED_CHARACTERS '"' with : ''' ALLOWED_CHARACTERS ''', I can correctly parse the input '{'Number':"Four"}'. So I think there is a problem with the double quotes ("). I tried also to replace PROPERTY with VALUE, but this doesn't work, too. Does anybody knows what I am doing wrong?
Input
{"Number":"Four"}

Grammar:
grammar Filter;

filter: expr+ EOF ;

expr
    : LBR expr RBR
    | PROPERTY ':' VALUE 
    ;

LBR: '{' ;
RBR: '}' ;
CLN: ':' ;
PRM: '"' ;

VALUE
    : TRUE
    | FALSE
    | INT
    | FLOAT
    | STRING
    ;

TRUE
    : 'true'
    ;
 
FALSE
    : 'false'
    ;

PROPERTY
    : '"' ALLOWED_CHARACTERS '"'
    ;
    
fragment ALLOWED_CHARACTERS 
    : ([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+
    ;

STRING
 : '"' (~['\r\n] | '\'\'')* '"'
 ;

INT
 : DIGIT+
 ;

FLOAT
 : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*
 | '.' DIGIT+
 ;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;

SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;


What tokens do you get with this? It seems the lexer would have difficulty distinguishing between STRING and PROPERTY tokens for certain character sequences.

In my Visitor Class the tokens { and } are recognized correctly. PROPERTY : VALUE, then fails.

thanks, you gave me the tipp. I removed PROPERTY and ALLOWED CHARACTER. Then I changed the Expression PROPERTY ':' VALUE to VALUE ':' VALUE. Now it works. I think, he had a problem to distinguished between VALUE and PROPERTY. Thank you :)

I removed PROPERTY and ALLOWED CHARACTER. Then I changed the Expression PROPERTY ':' VALUE to VALUE ':' VALUE. Now it works. I think, he had a problem to distinguished between VALUE and PROPERTY. Thank you :)
this is the working grammar:
grammar Filter;

filter: expr+ EOF ;

expr
    : LBR expr RBR
    | VALUE ':' VALUE 
    ;

LBR: '{' ;
RBR: '}' ;
CLN: ':' ;
PRM: '"' ;

VALUE
    : TRUE
    | FALSE
    | INT
    | FLOAT
    | STRING
    ;

TRUE
    : 'true'
    ;
 
FALSE
    : 'false'
    ;

STRING
 : '"' (~['\r\n] | '\'\'')* '"'
 ;

INT
 : DIGIT+
 ;

FLOAT
 : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*
 | '.' DIGIT+
 ;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;

SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;

